# Приложение использует слишком много ОЗУ C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Приложение работает с последовательным портом Serial, с Arduino проблема такова:

Спустя некоторое время работы программы, она начинает есть много оперативки и начинает тормозить, пытался решить проблему путем очистки оперативки программно. Но не помогло, первые 10 минут все нормально, быстродействие на высоте но после начинаются подвисания, жор оперативки и нагрузка на ЦП. Посоветуйте решения данной проблемы, как можно добиться стабильной работы приложения и снижения нагрузки на ЦП и ОЗУ?

**MainForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using TempDisplay.Properties;
using TempDisplay;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using CoreAudioApi;

namespace Serial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
        }
        MemoryManagement MM = new MemoryManagement();
        public class MemoryManagement
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr proc, int min, int max);

            public void FlushMemory()
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
                {
                    SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
                }
            }
        }
        private MMDevice device;
        MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
                return cp;
            }
        }

        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private delegate void updateDelegate(string txt);
        RegistryKey reg;
        string dir = Application.StartupPath + @"\LogTemperature\";
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setOpacity();
            if (Settings.Default.Autorun)
            {
                setAutorun(true);
            }
            else
            {
                setAutorun(false);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            arduinoPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            arduinoPort.DtrEnable = true;
            arduinoPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            try
            {
                arduinoPort.Open();
            }
            catch { 
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка открытия порта Serial.", "Ошибка!", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            //aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.Start();
            checkDir();
        }
        List<string> listTargetDay = new List<string>();
        public void checkDir()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 60000;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler((sender1, e1) =>
            {

                DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
                string year = localDate.Year.ToString();
                string mon = localDate.Month.ToString();
                string d = localDate.Day.ToString();
                if (localDate.Day < 10)
                {
                    d = d.Insert(0, "0");
                }
                if (localDate.Month < 10)
                {
                    mon = mon.Insert(0, "0");
                }
                if(!Directory.Exists(dir + year + @"\")){
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + year + @"\");
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir + year + @"\" + mon + @"\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + year + @"\" + mon + @"\");
                }
                string filename = dir + year + @"\" + mon + @"\" + d + ".tdi";
                switch (Settings.Default.tempChangeTime)
                {
                    case 15:
                        {
                            if (localDate.Minute == 15 || localDate.Minute == 30 || localDate.Minute == 45 || localDate.Minute == 0)
                            {
                                MM.FlushMemory();
                                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                                {
                                    string h = localDate.Hour.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Hour < 10)
                                    {
                                        h = h.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    string m = localDate.Minute.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Minute < 10)
                                    {
                                        m = m.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(temp + "/" + hum + "=" + h + ":" + m);
                                }
                            }
                        }break;
                    case 30:
                        {
                            MM.FlushMemory();
                            if (localDate.Minute == 30 || localDate.Minute == 0)
                            {
                                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                                {
                                    string h = localDate.Hour.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Hour < 10)
                                    {
                                        h = h.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    string m = localDate.Minute.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Minute < 10)
                                    {
                                        m = m.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(temp + "/" + hum + "=" + h + ":" + m);
                                }
                            }
                        }break;
                    case 60:
                        {
                            if (localDate.Minute == 0)
                            {
                                MM.FlushMemory();
                                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                                {
                                    string h = localDate.Hour.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Hour < 10)
                                    {
                                        h = h.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    string m = localDate.Minute.ToString();
                                    if (localDate.Minute < 10)
                                    {
                                        m = m.Insert(0, "0");
                                    }
                                    sw.WriteLine(temp + "/" + hum + "=" + h + ":" + m);
                                }
                            }
                        }break;
                }

            });
            timer1.Start();
        }

        public void setAutorun(bool mode)
        {
            try
            {
                reg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
                if (mode)
                {
                    reg.SetValue("TempDisplay", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
                }
                else
                {
                    reg.DeleteValue("TempDisplay");
                }
                reg.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        public int modeFSM = 0;
        public string strFromPort;
        int timer,timer2,timerVolume = 0;
        public bool IRMode = false;
        public long command;
        public bool volumeShowed = false;
        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!arduinoPort.IsOpen) return;
            try
            {
                arduinoPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                string testtxt = arduinoPort.ReadLine();
                if (testtxt != "")
                {
                    string left, right;
                    left = testtxt.Substring(0, testtxt.LastIndexOf("/"));

                    right = testtxt.Substring(testtxt.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).Trim();
                    if (left.Contains("|"))
                    {
                        IRMode = true;
                        command = long.Parse(left.Remove(left.LastIndexOf("|")).Trim());
                        left = left.Substring(left.LastIndexOf("|")+1);
                    }
                    if (left.Length < 3 && right.Length < 3)
                    {
                        if (left.Length != 0 && right.Length != 0)
                        {
                            temp = left.Trim();
                            hum = right.Trim();
                            strFromPort = testtxt;
                            if (strFromPort.Contains("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
                                Application.Exit();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (IRMode)
                                {
                                    switch (command)
                                    {
                                        case 970202566:
                                        case 3810943943:
                                        case 1574343947:
                                        case 25697026:
                                        case 970202567:
                                        case 1446504431:
                                        case 3051317709:
                                            {
                                                modeFSM = 1;
                                            }break;
                                        case 3768077238:
                                        case 772383768:
                                        case 3526445517:
                                        case 3037465025:
                                        case 2409342932:
                                        case 772337688:
                                        case 768077238:
                                        case 6807723738:
                                            {
                                                modeFSM = 2;
                                            } break;
                                        case 338831067:
                                        case 1141152792:
                                        case 7486132730:
                                        case 831063387:
                                        case 3868262230:
                                        case 388310637:
                                        case 2530296830:
                                        case 335918319:
                                            {
                                                modeFSM = 3;
                                            } break;
                                        case 924466310:
                                        case 663109244:
                                        case 924466311:
                                        case 4060279635:
                                        case 2603501675:
                                        case 322053449:
                                        case 878714008:
                                        case 488407073:
                                        case 4232468281:
                                        case 924466309:
                                            {
                                                modeFSM = 4;
                                            } break;
                                        case 2737486129:
                                        case 7486127329:
                                        case 370204530:
                                        case 8613273748:
                                        case 1875822595:
                                        case 2003704530:
                                        case 7374826130:
                                        case 7374826129:
                                        case 7374286129:
                                        case 2486558938:
                                            {
                                                modeFSM = 5;
                                            } break;
                                    }
                                    IRMode = false;
                                }
                                else { modeFSM = 0; }
                                if (timer != 0)
                                {
                                    timer = timer - 50;
                                }
                                if (timer2 != 0)
                                {
                                    timer2 = timer2 - 50;
                                }
                                if (timerVolume != 0)
                                {
                                    timerVolume = timerVolume - 50;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    FormVolume = new Volume();
                                }
                                label1.BeginInvoke(new updateDelegate(updateTextBox), strFromPort);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ed) {}
        }
        public int temperature;
        public int humidity;

        private FullScreenMode FormFullScreen = new FullScreenMode();
        private Volume FormVolume = new Volume();
        private void updateTextBox(string txt)
        {
            try
            {
                if (modeFSM == 2)
                {
                        label1.Text = temp + "° \n" + hum + "%";
                        temperature = int.Parse(temp.Trim());
                        humidity = int.Parse(hum.Trim());
                        notifyIcon1.Text = "Температура " + temp + "° \n" + "Влажность " + hum + "%";
                        if (ChangeTemp != null)
                        {
                            ChangeTemp.toolStripLabel1.Text = temp + "° | " + hum + "%";
                        }

                    if (timer == 0)
                    {
                        timer = Settings.Default.delayTime * 1000;
                        FormFullScreen = new FullScreenMode();
                        FormFullScreen.Tag = this;
                        FormFullScreen.Show();
                    }
                }
                if (modeFSM == 1)
                {
                        label1.Text = temp + "° \n" + hum + "%";
                        temperature = int.Parse(temp.Trim());
                        humidity = int.Parse(hum.Trim());
                        notifyIcon1.Text = "Температура " + temp + "° \n" + "Влажность " + hum + "%";
                        if (ChangeTemp != null)
                        {
                            ChangeTemp.toolStripLabel1.Text = temp + "° | " + hum + "%";
                        }

                    if (timer == 0)
                    {
                        timer = Settings.Default.delayTemp * 1000;
                        FormFullScreen = new FullScreenMode();
                        FormFullScreen.Tag = this;
                        FormFullScreen.Show();
                    }
                }
                if (modeFSM == 3)
                {
                    if (timer == 0)
                    {
                        timer = 200;
                        SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
                    }
                }
                if (modeFSM == 5)
                {
                    if (timer == 0)
                    {
                        timer = 50;
                        if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar != 0)
                        {
                            if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar > 0.05)
                            {
                                device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar - (float)0.05;
                            }
                            if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar < 0.05)
                            {
                                device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = 0;
                            }
                            if (timerVolume == 0)
                            {
                                FormVolume.Tag = this;
                                FormVolume.Show();
                            }
                            timerVolume = 2000;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (modeFSM == 4)
                {
                    if (timer == 0)
                    {
                        timer = 50;
                        if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar != 1)
                        {
                            if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar < 0.95)
                            {
                                device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar + (float)0.05;
                            }
                            if (device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar > 0.95)
                            {
                                device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = 1;
                            }
                            if (timerVolume == 0)
                            {
                                FormVolume.Tag = this;
                                FormVolume.Show();
                            }
                            timerVolume = 2000;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (modeFSM == 0)
                {
                    if (timer2 == 0)
                    {
                        label1.Text = temp + "° \n" + hum + "%";
                        notifyIcon1.Text = "Температура " + temp + "° \n" + "Влажность " + hum + "%";
                        if (ChangeTemp != null)
                        {
                            ChangeTemp.toolStripLabel1.Text = temp + "° | " + hum + "%";
                        }
                        timer2 = 2000;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        string temp, hum;
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            arduinoPort.Close();
        }
        bool mode = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (arduinoPort.IsOpen)
            {
                if (mode)
                {
                    arduinoPort.Write("1");

                }
                else
                {
                    arduinoPort.Write("0");
                }
                mode = !mode;
            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        public void setOpacity()
        {
            string opac = Settings.Default.opacityMain.ToString();
            if (Settings.Default.opacityMain != 100)
            {
                if (opac[1].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    opac = "0," + opac;
                }
                else { opac = "0," + opac[0]; }
                this.Opacity = double.Parse(opac);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Opacity = 1;
            }
        }
        private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (this.Visible)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    setOpacity();
                    this.Show();
                    this.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
        private SettingForm SettingF;
        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SettingF = new SettingForm();
            SettingF.Tag = this;
            SettingF.ShowDialog();
        }
        public int intervalinminutes = 100;
        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 1;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0.5;
        }

        TempChange ChangeTemp;
        private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeTemp = new TempChange();
            ChangeTemp.Tag = this;
            ChangeTemp.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Из области догадки: есть ли необходимость держать arduinoPort постоянно открытым? Вполне вероятно что он и ест.

Comment: @eblomyac он должен быть постоянно открытым, так как постоянно считываются значения с ИК-датчика(каждые 50 миллисекунд), а с датчика температуры и влажности каждые 2 секунды. Спасибо за догадку, буду проверять.

Comment: В вашем коде очень сложно разобраться. Насчёт утечек, насколько я понимаю, GC не обязан освобождать память как вам этого захочется.  Начните с того, что надо осмотреть все места создания экземпляров объектов, надо постараться минимизировать их количество. Если объект создаётся в ограниченной области (например, в функции/методе), можно в момент когда объект больше не нужен, явно присваивать ему null (чтобы увеличить вероятность срабатывания триггера GC). Во всяком случае,  подобные рекомендации я не однократно встречал. Вам бы ещё код в порядок привести...

Comment: Разрешите уточнить, вы привели код на PC, именно он "тормозит" и ест ОЗУ? Или же, тормозит сама Arduino?

Comment: @test123 спасибо за совет. Тормозит код на PC, с работой Arduino все в порядке.